# what is the 'QUANTITY|TAG' for in eth_call

Tags: json-rpc

How does that parameter affect eth_call?

From the doc, this should specify a block? Does that mean it is as if the transaction were in the block?

Answer (score 1):

- `QUANTITY` => block number
- `|` => or
- `TAG` => one of the following strings: `"latest"`, `"earliest"` or `"pending"`

There's also an explanation for this in  ["The default block parameter"](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#the-default-block-parameter) part of the wiki:

> When requests are made that act on the state of ethereum, the last
> default block parameter determines the height of the block.
>
> The following options are possible for the defaultBlock parameter:
>
> - HEX String - an integer block number
> - HEX String - block hash
> - String "earliest" for the earliest/genesis block
> - String "latest" - for the latest mined block
> - String "pending" - for the pending state/transactions

Comment: so if I specify the blocknum as =N=, then all blocks after =N= are ignored?  EVM will process the transaction as if the chain is only of length =N= ?  I guess in that case it would cost much CPU to maintain snapshots based on different =N=.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You're just making a call on the state in that block. You don't have snapshots based on different `N`, the client would just query the known state for that block. (This works because of how the state data is organised.)